# How to jump to a string in vim ex mode using a bash script

Tags: bash, vim, terminal, ex, ex-mode

I want to move to the word "internal" in a text file "file1" and delete everything from there to the end of file from within a bash script. This is my vim command sequence :

```
/internal
execute "normal !dG"
w
```

When I save this in a text file and pass it to vim from the command line in ex mode, everything works fine. But when I try to do this from the terminal command prompt from outside vim :

`echo "/internal | execute "normal! dG" | w" | vim -e file1`

it doesn't work. I cat out file1 and I find that it hasn't changed. The text file file1 looks like this:

```
one 
one 
one 
one 
one 

internal

two
two
two
two
two
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to work from the terminal command prompt ?

Comment: It did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `/internal | exec(...`, all the string will be interpreted by `/`. You can write `/internal` on its own line. Like this:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat file
1
2
foo
3
4
[STEP 102] $ printf 'norm gg\n/foo\n.,$p|q\n' | vim -e file
foo
3
4
[STEP 103] $
```

Or use the `search()` function:

```
[STEP 104] $ echo 'exec("norm gg") | call search("foo") | .,$p | q' | vim -e file
foo
3
4
[STEP 105] $
```